# .htaccess issue for 301 redirect url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to use 301 redirects for my website URLs. The URL redirects to the wrong path and the website give me a 404 error. When I use this redirect.

```
Redirect 301 /couponstore/evitamins-120 https://website.com/codes/evitamins-coupon-codes
```

it gives me a result like this

```
https://website.com/codes/evitamins-coupon-codes?lcp=couponstore/evitamins-120
```

the `lcp=couponstore/evitamins-120` is an extra part and it is injected to the URL due to the .htaccess rewrite. When I remove the last part of the rewrite rule `^((.*?)(\-(\d+))?)([.]\w+)?$ index.php?lcp=$1&lcp_id=$4&ext=$5 [QSA,L]` then my website stop working and I am getting errors on all pages.

Below is the .htaccess code for my website:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on
## Coupons CMS v7
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((.*?)(\-(\d+))?)([.]\w+)?$ index.php?lcp=$1&lcp_id=$4&ext=$5 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

what should I do to use redirects for my website URLs, I lost all the SEO for my website due to this one issue which I am not capable to resolve, need suggestion/help to redirect old URLs to the new.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine ON
## Coupons CMS v7

RewriteRule ^(couponstore/evitamins-120)/?$ codes/evitamins-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((.*?)(\-(\d+))?)([.]\w+)?$ index.php?lcp=$1&lcp_id=$4&ext=$5 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I implement this code, upon checking on another browser it redirects to wrong place and now in URL I see is the directory path, like this `https://website.com/home/folder/public_html/codes/evitamins-coupon-codes`

Comment: @TutorialLab, could you please change RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^(couponstore/evitamins-120)/?$ /codes/evitamins-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]` once and let me know how it goes then?

Comment: sure, i will try this now

Comment: still no luck, getting the above url upon redirect.

Comment: @TutorialLab, ok could you please do let me know 2 things, 1- what is the URL you want to see? 2- where is your htaccess placed in your folder structure?

Comment: also, my server is using nginx proxy with apache. mod security is turned off.

Comment: I have a VPS where i Installed CWP, and website is hosted on it's own account. and .htaccess file is located in the public_html folder (root directory).

old URL: https://website.com/couponstore/evitamins-120
new URL: https://website.com/codes/evitamins-coupon-codes

the URL structure is changed and I want to redirect old URL to the new URL.

Comment: The url is now redirecting to correct page without 404 error, but in the URL I am still getting this extra part `?lcp=couponstore/evitamins-120` how this can be removed? 
thanks